# Google Maps API default call vs Google Maps js api loader

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to develop a plugin for the no-code Bubble platform based on the Google Maps api.
As I am not an advanced coder, I started taking a look to an existing plugin which is free and open source.
There I could notice the author utilizes a script called "google maps js api loader" instead of the api call suggested by the Google Maps api reference, i.e. adding the script

```
<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
```

Browsing to the js api loader Github page, it is stated that

> Load the Google Maps JavaScript API script dynamically. This takes
> inspiration from the google-maps npm package but updates it with ES6,
> Promises, and TypeScript.

And, browsing to the google maps loader npm package page, it is stated:

> Async loader for google maps api.
>
> This module does not change original google maps api in any way. It
> just provide easy way to load and use this API asynchronously.

So, maybe (really likely) for my lack of experience, I was guessing: which are the differencies between these two ways to load Google Maps api and which advantages one can get by loading those asynchronously? 
Thank you!

Comment: Well, as per the description of the package itself, that "it does not change original google maps api in any way. It just provides an easy way to load and use this API asynchronously." So the difference would be how you load the script tag for Maps Javascript API, and the advantage would be that it would be easier to do so. And you can do so dynamically, since you don't have to hardcode it on the html file.

Comment: @Yrll thank you! Observing better the js api loader script, I have got that with that you can, for example, define the api key and other parameters as variables which are then passed to the loader that "builds by itself" the api call...is this maybe the meaning of dynamically loading vs hardcoding?

Comment: Yeap, I think it would also be a good way to prevent your API key being hardcoded on your html file. Which could somehow be a more secure way of storing your API key on your app I guess. Since you can put a variable in it and not the actual API key.

Comment: The call to the API will still include the key... The only way to make your API key secure is to [restrict it](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices).